# Laplace question

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

How do you express Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}(g)(z)=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-zt}g(t)dt$ with Fourier transform? And how do you form the reverse formula for Laplace transform using Laplace transform value $\mathcal{L}(g)(\sigma + \mathbf{i}y)$, $y\in \Bbb{R}$. We can assume the functions are integrable.

Comment: If the imaginary axis is contained in the region of convergence of the Laplace transform, then $({\cal F} g)(\omega) = ({\cal L} g)(i \omega)$. (You may need to allow for scaling depending on your version of the Fourier transform, some have ${1 \over 2 \pi}$ or ${1 \over \sqrt{2 \pi}}$ scaling factors.)

Comment: I don't understand your reverse formula question.

Comment: @ELEC  please see my answer,is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

laplace transform introduce variable $s$  as $s=\sigma+j*\omega$,

if $\sigma=0$   then lapalce transform is same as fourier transform,which means that  laplace transform only on imaginary part is equivalent to fourier transform

Comment: So if fourier transform is $\hat{g}(\mathcal{v})=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2i\pi\mathcal{v}t}g(t)dt$ using this to form the Laplace transform we get $\hat{g}(\mathcal{v})=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-st}g(t)dt$ and when $\sigma=0$ and $\omega=2\pi$ we get fourier transform $\hat{g}(\mathcal{v})=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2i\pi\mathcal{v}t}g(t)dt$? or something :D

Comment: when you  put in lapalce trasnform $\sigma=0$,then you get fourier transform

Comment: yeah got it! but... the laplace transform is from $0 \to \infty$ and the fourier is in whole $\Bbb{R}$. what's up with that?

Comment: there could be  bilateral laplace transform,please see this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-sided_Laplace_transform

Comment: any question  please?if not please   confirm  that problem was solved :)

Comment: Thanks! still unsure about the second question. my prof gave a hint: Function $v \to \mathcal{L}(g)(\sigma + i2\pi v)$ is a fourier transform of a certain function. Express this function with reverse fourier transform. hmm

Comment: you know right  inverse fourier transform formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply that info sadly :(

Comment: show it ti professor,if something is wrong,he will fix,dont worry,we are learning from  experienced people